# Automatically add node to menu

Tags: 8, navigation

How can I automatically create a menu link for a new node in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a deriver class for this.

### In your `foo.links.menu.yml` file

```
entity.node.canonical:
  deriver: '\Drupal\foo\Plugin\Deriver\FooMenuLinkDeriver'
  route_name: entity.node.canonical
```

### In `Drupal\foo\Plugin\Deriver\FooMenuLinkDeriver`

```
class FooMenuLinkDeriver extends DeriverBase implements ContainerDeriverInterface {
  public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base) {
    $plugin_definitions = [];
    foreach (Node::loadMultiple() as $nid => $node) {
      $plugin_definitions[$nid] = $base;
      $plugin_definitions[$nid]['route_parameters']['node'] = $nid;
      $plugin_definitions[$nid]['title'] = $node->label();
    }
    return $plugin_definitions; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you will need a custom module implementing `hook_entity_presave` or `hook_entity_insert`

`hook_entity_insert` would be called only when a NEW node is created
`hook_entity_presave` would be called any time a node is saved/updated

```
<?php
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use \Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent;

function MODULE_NAME_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity){

    if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node') {    
        $title = $entity->getTitle();
        //OR
        //$title = $entity->title->value;
        $nid = $entity->id();

        $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create([
          'title' => $title,
          'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node/' . $nid],
          'menu_name' => 'main',
          'expanded' => TRUE,
        ]);
        $menu_link->save();
    }
}
?>
```

If you use `hook_entity_presave` you might need to check whether the MENU item exists otherwise you will end up with a new menu item each time the node is updated.

```
<?php
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use \Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent;

function MODULE_NAME_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity){

    if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node') {    
        $title = $entity->getTitle();
        //OR
        //$title = $entity->title->value;
        $nid = $entity->id();           

        $menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');

        $menu_links = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $nid));
        if(sizeof($menu_links)){
            foreach ($menu_links as $menu_link) {
                $definition = $menu_link->getPluginDefinition();
                $definition['title'] = $title;
                $menu_link_manager->updateDefinition($menu_link->getPluginId(), $definition);
                //PHP warning pending fix https://www.drupal.org/node/2775665
            }
        }else{
            $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create([
                'title' => $title,
                'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node/' . $nid],
                'menu_name' => 'main',
                'expanded' => TRUE,
            ]);
            $menu_link->save();
        }
    }
}
```

To get the basic of custom modules please look here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules

for similar question and answers for drupal 7 look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163537/drupal-automatically-add-menu-items-when-new-nodes-are-added